# How to obtain sliced sublists of a list dynamically in python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

And I want to obtain a sequence of lists in this logic:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[3,4],[2,3],[1,2],[0,1],[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

That's it, sublists made of `l[1:]` and `l[:-1]`

I started by this recursive function:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4]

def sublist(l):

    if len(l) == 1:
        return l
    else:
        return [sublist(l[1:]),sublist(l[:-1])]

a = [sublist(l)]

print a
```

But it's not really what I what as it outputs:

```
[[[[[[4], [3]], [[3], [2]]], [[[3], [2]], [[2], [1]]]], [[[[3], [2]], [[2], [1]]], [[[2], [1]], [[1], [0]]]]]]
```

Comment: Well after all I agree, check my edit @freakish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very straightforward implementation:

```
def sublists_n(l, n):
    subs = []
    for i in range(len(l)-n+1):
        subs.extend([l[i:i+n]])
    return subs

def sublists(l):
    subs = []
    for i in range(len(l)-1,0,-1):
        subs.extend(sublists_n(l,i))
    return subs

>>> l = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> sublists(l)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: Really *straightforward*. Great :)

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
[list(itertools.combinations(l, x)) for x in range(1, len(l))]
```

Comment: Better than my answer.

Comment: Aha! So I was right after all. I saw itertools and assumed there was a totally sweet std lib thing I'd missed.

Comment: Nope. Just a quick trigger finger. I still think it could be a one-liner though.

Answer (score 1):

```
[l[x:] for x in range(len(l))] + [l[:x+1] for x in range(len(l))]
```

Loops through `l` twice, but you sort of have to no matter what I think (could use `zip` but same thing).

Comment: I get quite confused as how it works, but great, almost makes it!

Comment: The idea is that you create two lists, one with `l[x:]` for every x less than the length of `l` and one with `l[:x+1]` (the offset is because of the way slicing works in Python)  for the same set of numbers. Then you just put them together. I think it actually works... :(

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursion, doesn't quite order things correctly but its simple.

```
def sublists(l):
    right = l[1:]
    left = l[:-1]
    result = [right, left]
    if len(l) > 2:
        result.extend(sublists(right))
        result.extend(sublists(left))
    return result

print sublists([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: also I think some values are repeated. I'm not sure your question is clear on exactly what is needed.